# Show bottom navigation bar inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar, bottomnavigationview

I want to show Bottom Navigation View **inside** a fragment just like Instagram. First of all is it possible to add bottom navigation view inside fragment? And if yes, then how?

This is inside onCreateView:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                toolbar.setTitle("Home");
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_attend:
                toolbar.setTitle("Attendance");
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_inquire:
                toolbar.setTitle("Inquiry");
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_help:
                toolbar.setTitle("Help Desk");
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_setting:
                toolbar.setTitle("Profile");
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

And according to https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/ we've to use:

```
ActionBar toolbar = getSupportActionBar();
toolbar.setTitle("Home");
```

But I know this isn't working...
Thanks in advance